# Device Product Code API call

Tags: openfda, medical

I'm trying to return medical device "product_code" data, but the following two URLs do not work. For example, I'm trying to get data on the product code, "DXN" as listed here:
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfPCD/classification.cfm?ID=822.

*Any thoughts on what is missing?*

// 2x NON-FUNCTIONAL CALLS:

https://api.fda.gov/device/510k.json?search=openfda.product_code:dxn

https://api.fda.gov/device/510k.json?search=product_code:dxn

Answer (score 0):

The `product_code` field is at the top level (*not* nested under `openfda`), so only the second query would be correct. Also, the value should be capitalized: `DXN`.

This query will produce results you need: https://api.fda.gov/device/510k.json?search=product_code:DXN